# Python delete firefox history

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to clean the history of Chrome and Firefox (Windows 10 x64). What I do is delete the files that store the data. My code work's great for Chrome, but it seems like firefox can't find the path.

```
def fileDel(paths,item):
if (os.path.exists(paths)):
    os.remove(paths)
    print "Deleted %s in %s" % (item,paths)
else:
    print paths
    print "No %s found" % (item)
```

The way I define the paths of the files is below.

```
firefox_places = os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"Users", users_name, "AppData", "Roaming","Mozilla","Firefox","Profiles", ff_profile ,"places")
chrome_history_path = os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"Users", users_name, "AppData", "Local","Google","Chrome","User Data","Default","History")
```

The ff_profile is the name of the `{random}.default` folder.

```
Firefox Profile Found: qbnoewat.default 
Deleted Chrome History in C:\Users\marduc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
C:\Users\marduc\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qbnoewat.default\places
No ff found
```

The absolute path of the file is:
`C:\Users\marduc\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qbnoewat.default\places`

The path is right but it seems it can't find the file. I also tried to hardcode the exact path but nothing happened. 
Is there some other way I could do it, or there is something wrong in my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data):

> Bookmarks, Downloads and Browsing History: The **places.sqlite** file
>   contains all your Firefox bookmarks and lists of all the files you've
>   downloaded and websites you’ve visited.

If you change

```
firefox_places = os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"Users", users_name, "AppData", "Roaming","Mozilla","Firefox","Profiles", ff_profile ,"places.sqlite")
```

i.e. add `.sqlite`, your code should work (tested on Win10).

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to enable file extensions in order to see the whole file.